# Flex List Add a label and show text

Tags: apache-flex, list

I am trying to add an item to a list and have text display and have a different hidden value when i access selected items.  I also need to do this with a loop.

Currently i am trying to add a label and set the labels id to my value. But the list just shows the ID and not the text. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var theLabel:Label = new Label();
theLabel.id = "123";
theLabel.text = "test";             
lstLayerList_array.addItem(theLabel);

<s:List id="lstLayerList" >
    <s:dataProvider>                
        <s:ArrayList id="lstLayerList_array">               
        </s:ArrayList>              
    </s:dataProvider>
</s:List>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var theLabel:Label = new Label();
theLabel.id = "123";
theLabel.text = "test";             
lstLayerList_array.addItem(theLabel);

<s:List id="lstLayerList" labelField="text">
    <s:dataProvider>                
        <s:ArrayList id="lstLayerList_array">               
        </s:ArrayList>              
    </s:dataProvider>
</s:List>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the labelField property to theLabel.text.

Comment: Isn't that what theLabel.text = "test";  is doing? How do i set the property. Thanks!!!!